# Prove the complex conjugate of an analytic function is analytic in the set of conjugates.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

Given a function $f(z) \in C$ that is analytic, prove that $g(z) = \overline{f(\bar z)}$ is analytic in the set $\{\bar z : z \in C \}$.  This is for homework: tips would be appreciated.

Comment: $\{\bar z : z \in \Bbb C \}=\Bbb C$, take $f(z)=z$, this is not true.

Comment: The identity function is entire, but the complex conjugate function isn't.

Comment: Maybe $g(z)=\overline{f(\bar z)}$?

Comment: @Hamou Yes, that is correct.  I misread the problem because the type was so small.

Answer (score 2):

$f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ analytic ,hence $g(z)=\sum \bar a_n z^n$ is analytic.